# NuxtJS Vue Bootstrap - this.$bvModal undefined

Tags: nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I have installed `@nuxtjs/bootstrap-vue` version 2.0.4.
The documentation says that VueBootstrap will automatically inject into each component the this.$bvModal object but in my case when I invoke this.$bvModal it says `undefined`. I need this to programatically close an opened modal. Here's the `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
export default {
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: false,

  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'schedule-app',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    '@/assets/scss/app.scss'
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/lodash.js',
    '~/plugins/mixins.js'
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/eslint
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module'
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/bootstrap-vue',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    '@nuxtjs/i18n',
    '@nuxtjs/moment',
    'nuxt-sweetalert2'
  ],

  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          property: 'token',
          global: true,
          required: true,
          type: 'Bearer'
        },
        user: {
          property: 'data',
          autoFetch: true
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/api/schedule/authentication/login',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'token'
          },
          user: {
            url: '/api/schedule/companies/current',
            method: 'get',
            propertyName: 'data'
          },
          logout: {
            url: '/api/schedule/authentication/logout',
            method: 'post'
          }
        },
        tokenType: 'Bearer'
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/',
      logout: false,
      home: false
    }
  },

  i18n: {
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'en',
        file: 'en-us.js'
      }
    ],
    lazy: true,
    langDir: 'lang/',
    defaultLocale: 'en'
  },

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost-api.dev'
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
  }
}
```

So I have a modal with id `schedule-popup-modal` which looks like this:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" v-b-modal.modal-schedule-popup>{{ $t('phrases.view_complete_event_schedule') }}</button>
              
<b-modal
  id="modal-schedule-popup"
  class="modal-schedule-list"
  size="lg"
  :title="$t('phrases.schedule_list')"
  hide-footer>
  Test
</b-modal>
```

When you click the "View Complete Event Schedule" button the modal does show. Now I want to close the modal with `this.$bvModal.hide('modal-schedule-list')` but the access to this.$bvModal in any component is `undefined` (`$vm0.$bvModal` is `undefined`).

Comment: Hi, we will probably need a [repro] here or some kind of code to troubleshoot.

Comment: [@nuxtjs/bootstrap-vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/bootstrap-vue) is 4 years old and has been deprecated. [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#nuxtjs-module) comes with a Nuxt module that you should use instead.